# Is it possible to create a RESTful WCF service as JSON passthrough not declaring ServiceKnownType

Tags: c#, json, wcf, web-services, rest

I have a C# WCF RESTful service acting as a JSON pass-through, meaning my service does an HTTPGet to another RESTful service - receives a JSON response back and I need to return that response to my caller.  The reason for this pass-through service is our enterprise does not allow different domains to communicate and this will be publicly exposed as a solution.  When the known type is included in this service everything works fine, however that means the middle service is forced to be updated/republished for every DataContract change when it should not care what JSON was received to send back to the caller.

I tried using JSON.NET to deserialize a JSON string into a dynamic object. Despite my service contract saying it will return a dynamic type and all complies, I get a ServiceKnownType serialization error at runtime. I cannot declare KnownType dynamically at runtime b/c I want my service to know nothing about the type.

(A) Web App in Domain X --> (B) my public facing service --> (C) RESTful WCF Service on Domain Y

Is it possible to not even deserialize the JSON recieved and send it out in the response?
Other ideas? Would any code be helpful to better describe myself?

Thanks!

This is the solution thanks to L.B. :)

```
            //Call other WS  and get the Json response
            var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            string text;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    text = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    var data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = data.Length;

                    return data;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method that returns a *Stream* (It can be thought as *"return any object"*)

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Stream SomeMethod(......)
{
    //Call other WS  and get the Json response

    var data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = data.Length;

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Of course one wonders why bothering with  *I tried using JSON.NET to deserialize a JSON string into a dynamic object.* Perhaps there's something added in the public facing service other than acting as a passthrough.

Comment: @ConradFrix - There is nothing added in the middle service.  I tried using it in an attempt to get desired result.  I will recreate error to include text for further assistance.

Comment: @L.B. I got your solution to work, however it treated it like a string and added quotes to everything and not returning a true JSON object.  I added attempted code in original question.  IE- {"ActionItemColor":"00fa08","AppProvisionDate":"2013-11-06T16:55:26","AppVersion":"2.6.3","BackgroundTextureImageID":"2", ...

Comment: @AdventurGurl Nope. It doesn't treat it as string. I just tested it and it works as it should. There must be something you are not showing us.

Comment: @L.B. - Indeed, you are correct and I was mistaken! Thank you sooo much!! The (A) in scenario above just tested the response they are receiving and worked like a charm.  The code I added too my original question using your solution is the entire method (plus try/catch).